# How to plan CIRC motions with Pilz Industrial Motion Planner using arbitrary reference coordinate systems?

Tags: ros-humble, motion-planning, moveit2

**Tl;dr:** I want to rotate the link at the end of the planning group around the X-axis of the center point in clockwise direction by theta degrees. How would I do that?

I want to plan industrial motions (PTP, LIN, CIRC) using `Pilz Industrial Motion Planner (PIMP)`. I am generally able to achieve that either in `RViz` and also with MotionPlanRequest via `move_group` in the world coordinate system. The goal is to plan motions in arbitrary reference frames (link coordinate systems) of the robot model. The problem is, that the CIRC motion expects that the `frame_id` is the same ID as the robot model frame (`robot_model->getModelFrame()`). All underlying functions like `moveit::core::RobotState::setFromIK(...)` assume that the reference frame (:=`frame_id`) is equal to the reference frame of the kinematic model. Therefore, the usage of another reference frame via `frame_id` is prohibited. I'm now considering writing another overload for `setFromIK` in order to plan for arbitrary reference frames.

Is there another way to achieve that, using functions that are already implemented?